# Get current latitude and longitude from didupdatelocation delegate method

Tags: ios, xcode6, cllocationmanager

I created a MAPVIEW to get latitude and longitude of user's current location.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

The `didUpdateLocations` delegate method gives an array which has current location's latitude and longitude.
How do i get latitude and longitude from that array?

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method will return the array of `CLLocation` objects. This array contains most recent location at end of array.

So, you should receive it like this:

```
CLLocation *loc = [locations lastObject];
```

To access latitude, longitude write below code.

```
CLLocationDegrees latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `locations` array, you will find CLLocation objects. From there, you can get the coordinates like this:

```
CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:someIndex]; //You can have more than one update so loop through it.
CLLocationDegrees latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
```

Comment: Great ! Please consider to accept the answer if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below method of delegate to get current location of user.

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the last object from the locations array and then grab the lattitude and longitude by the way.

```
CLLocation *location  = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocationDegrees lattitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation * currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
NSString * latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString * longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```